# Obter métodos criados pelo usuário

Tags: c#, .net, reflexão

Tenho um método que lista os métodos que determinado objeto tem, quero pegar apenas os métodos criados pelo usuário, nesse caso: **Somar** e **Subtrair**.

O que esse método me retorna:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Classe Genérica**

```
public class Generico
{
    public object Objeto { get; set; }

    public string[] ListarMetodos()
    {
        var m = Objeto.GetType().GetMethods();
        string[] metodos = new string[m.Length];

        for (int i = 0; i < m.Length; i++)
            metodos[i] = String.Concat(i, " [+] ", m[i].Name, "\n");
        return metodos;
    }
}
```

**Classe Exemplo**

```
public class Calculadora
{
    public int x { get; set; }
    public int y { get; set; }

    public Calculadora() { }

    public int Somar()
    {
        return this.x + this.y;
    }

    public int Subtrair()
    {
        return this.x - this.y;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
var m = Objeto.GetType().GetMethods(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly).Where(x => !x.IsSpecialName).ToArray();
```

Comment: Cigano, deu quase certo, mas agora ele continua mostrando os métodos de get da classe, tem como filtrar isso também?

Comment: @NULL Se tiver, ótimo, mas se não tiver filtre manualmente os resultados por [`MethodInfo.isSpecialName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.reflection.methodbase.isspecialname)

Comment: +1 pelo `BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly`... essa eu não sabia. Só sabia com `DeclaringType`.

Comment: Obrigado @mgibsonbr, editei a resposta do Cigano com esse complemento que você deu.

Answer (score 5):

Você pode verificar em qual tipo está a declaração do método usando a propriedade `DeclaringType` do `MethodInfo`, assim pode filtrar da forma que quiser:

```
public string[] ListarMetodos()
{
    var t = Objeto.GetType();
    return t.GetMethods()
        .Where(mi => mi.DeclaringType == t)
        .Where(x => !x.IsSpecialName)
        .Select((mi, i) => i + " [+] " + mi.Name)
        .ToArray();
}
```

Comment: Testei aqui Miguel, não retornou nenhum método.

Comment: Que estranho... aqui funciona normalmente.

Comment: @MiguelAngelo Usando LINQ, que tal expandir o `Where()` para garantir a segurança do retorno?

Comment: Como assim? Você quer dizer para eu fazer um `foreach` ao invés de usar LINQ?

Comment: @mgibsonbr Tomei a liberdade de colocar também o filtro para remover getters/setters e outros métodos especiais.

Comment: Eu ia dizer `Where(mi => mi.DeclaringType == t && !mi.IsSpecialName)`, mas foram mais rápidos :P

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Acho que entendi... Editei... vê se era isso que você estava falando.

Comment: Aqui vai um empurrão... parabéns pelos 10k !

Comment: Valeu... Esse dígito foi difícil, agora só quero ver o próximo. Talvez eu esteja vivo até lá! =D